# Colunas dinâmicas na view mongodb

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

Olá,

Estou com um job onde preciso criar uma view um mongo db, porém algumas colunas dessa view devem ser calculadas em tempo de execução, similar ao NOW() do mysql, por exemplo: Quando eu fizer um find na view, preciso que uma coluna venha com a data atual.

Tentei criar a view setando um campo com o valor

```
{"meucampo": new Date()}
```

Mais o mongo executa o date e grava somente o resultado fixo e quando vou consultar a coluna `meucampo` ele simplesmente mostra a data de quando criei a view rsrs

Se puderem me ajudar por favor

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso na aplicação, o mais próximo que o mongodb tem nesse sentido é o [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/).

Espero que ajude. Se precisar de algo a mais, cola um trecho do código da aplicação.